# Highlight start of week Javascript/JQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have the datepicker working and it is fully functional.

[image: Datepicker - Week is not highlighted]

From the above image it can be seen that the week picker works. However I would like the datepicker to highlight the current week. Which in this example should highlight whole of the start of the week. Which I would like to look like this or similar[image: What I would like]

How is this done?

Edited 
Ideally when the page loads up I would like the current week to be highlighted instead of the user having to select the week themselves. In the example supplied, the day is currently selected but I wish to have the current week automatically selected. Like below

[image: Current Week already selected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TD` that is selected has the class `ui-datepicker-current-day`, so that might be what you want to find. You can do the highlighting by attaching a click event with the datepicker element, e.g.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().click(function(event) {
    // highlight the TR
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").parent().addClass('highlight');

    // highlight the TD > A
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").siblings().find('a').addClass('highlight2');
});
```

And you can define the `highlight` and `highlight2` classes to your heart's content.

Note that, the `onSelect` event does not do the trick, as the calendar is refreshed each time a date is clicked.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9DdfL/2/

Comment: Your example that you supplied is precisily what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

each row of dates in the datepicker is a `<tr>`. the `<td>` element which contains today's date has the class `ui-datepicker-today`.
therefore, you can search for the parent of this element to get the corresponding tr and assign whatever class you want to it:
`$(".ui-datepicker-today").parent().addClass(...)`

Comment: I don't know where the parent element is corressponding to.

Comment: the parent element is the `<tr>` which contains the row you've highlighted in green. I suggest you use firebug or some other developer tool to check out the html markup for youreslf.

Comment: I checked out the html using firebug and i understand that each week is seperated int <tr>. I have edited my post further to explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: Usually with the normal datepicker a user has to select a day. However I want the current week selected prior to when the page is loaded. Is this possible

Comment: what do you mean 'selected'? you'd like the result of `datepicker('getDate')` to be a range of dates?